# Getting VECM parameters from Johansen cointegration function in statsmodels

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, statsmodels

I'm trying to obtain the estimates of the parameter values associated with the reduced-rank VEC(q) model of my ECM model y_t. I understand that the Johansen Cointegration test does this but reading the `statsmodels` function documentation [here](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/_modules/statsmodels/tsa/vector_ar/vecm.html#coint_johansen), its unclear how I could adapt this code to do this. It appears to be a feature of the [Matlab Johansen Cointegration function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/econ/jcitest.html), but not the Python one which just outputs the trace and max eigenvalues statistics and critical values. I was wondering if I could get help with this.

**Edit**: The final line of the function is return `JohansenTestResult(rkt, r0t, a, d, lr1, lr2, cvt, cvm, aind)` and from `JohansenTestResult` class it can be seen that `a = eig` and `d=evec`. And `ad` and `au` appear to be the original eigenvalues and eigenvectors prior to a cholesky decomposition and transformation which gives a and d, which are just `ad` and `au` ordered by magnitude of the eigenvalues.  I found that `print(d*a*inv(d))` may give me the necessary matrix of coefficients. But theyre both 4*4 matrices for my 3 explanatories and 1 dependent, and I am thus wondering how to obtain the 1*4 vector of coefficients.

Comment: what is du, au, a, d? Explain what they mean and include the code snippet where you assign them a value.

Comment: @JuanCarlosRamirez The final line of the function is `return JohansenTestResult(rkt, r0t, a, d, lr1, lr2, cvt, cvm, aind)` and from `JohansenTestResult` class it can be seen that `a = eig` and `d=evec` `ad` and `au` appear to be the original eigenvalues and eigenvectors prior to a cholesky decomposition and transformation which gives `a` and `d`

Comment: My code calling the function is as follows, `result = coint_johansen(self.data, -1, 1)` and I just have a print statement in the function, `print(du*au*inv(du)) `

Comment: You should specify that in your question, visitors to your question might not be familiar with the notation and directly including that info creates more value.

Comment: @JuanCarlosRamirez Sorted it out.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation, the method outputs a JohansenTestResult. From looking at the  [JohansenTestResult guide,](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.vector_ar.vecm.JohansenTestResult.html) we see that  the object stores the VECM eigenvectors and eigenvalues in the

`evec` and `eig` properties, respectively

Comment: Thanks. But adding `print(du*au*inv(du))` appears to give me a 4*4 vector for my ECM y_t having 3 explanatories and 1 dependent. I was expecting a 1*4 vector reepresenting the coefficients

Comment: You have to transform the eigenvectors to recover the coefficients, if you do not want to do this and you mainly care about the parameters, I recommend using the VECM class directly, to fit the model which will output a VECMResult object containing the coefficients, see https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.vector_ar.vecm.VECM.html and https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.vector_ar.vecm.VECMResults.html#statsmodels.tsa.vector_ar.vecm.VECMResults

Comment: If I wanted to carry out the transformations, what would I need to do here? Also, this is more a question about the Johansen test, but arent we working with a reduced-rank VECM in this test?

Comment: Are you referring to just finding the eigenvector associated with the highest eigenvalue and that would be the coefficent matrix, as is described here (https://www.quantstart.com/articles/Johansen-Test-for-Cointegrating-Time-Series-Analysis-in-R/)